# Catch the placeholder value of input text box

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is to catch the placeholder's content of input text.

Here is the jQuery code I use to try catch the placeholder value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','.btn-outline-secondary', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
    alert(id);
    var testo = $(this).closest('.input-group mb-3').find('.form-control').attr('placeholder');
    alert(testo);
    var thisObject = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
    var data_1 = 'testo=' + testo + '&id=' + id; 
    if(confirm("nome corretto?")){
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
       data: data_1,
       url: "php/nome_video.php"
     })
      .done(function(){
        $(".div_check").show();
        $('.div_check').fadeOut(2000);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

and this is the html code of the page:

```
    $html .="<div class='div_testo'>";

    $html .= "<div class='input-group mb-3'>";
    $html .= "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='input-testo' placeholder='metti il nome del video' aria-label='nome del video' aria-describedby='basic-addon2'>";
    $html .= "</div><!-- end input-group mb-3-->";
    $html .= "<div class='input-group-append'>";
    $html .= "<button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' type='button' rel='id=$rows1[id]'>SALVA</button>";
    $html .= "<div class='div_check'><img src='./loghi/checkmark.svg' width='24' height='24'></div><!-- end checkmark -->";     
    $html .= "</div><!-- end input-group-append-->";

    $html .= "</div><!-- end div_testo -->";
```

I used the closest function because as far as I understood, this function goes up in the dom element and should catch the closest to the element that started the action.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `input-group mb-3` is not a parent of the button.  It is a sibling of it's parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var testo = $(this)
    .closest('.div_testo')
    .find('.input-group.mb-3 .form-control')
    .attr('placeholder');
```

`.div_testo` is the shared parent of the element you click and the element you are trying to find.
`.input-group.mb-3` is not a parent of the button

Comment: Thanks now i am catching the placeholder value but for some reason it doesn't catch what I typed in but only the original string "metti il nome del video"

Comment: Typing into an element does not change the placeholder.  It changes the value.  The placeholder is what shows when there is not a value, thus it being named "placeholder"

Comment: What exactly are you after?  I'm slightly confused now.  If all you are after is the value the user typed in, you want to get the `val()` and ignore the placeholder.

Comment: yes that's it.. my  mistake, i guessed that the placeholder, in someways, replaced (in bootstrap4) the value element..

Comment: your answer was correct so thank you very much for your help and for helping me to understand the difference between placeholder and value and to help me understand the parent and siblings hierarchy

Comment: Yep, remember that the DOM is a tree structure, and html indentation to show element nesting is an easy way to see which elements are a parent to other elements, and help you visualize the tree